# Internet Explorer 9/JavaScript: Disable confirm alert/pop-up for ActiveX

Tags: javascript, activex, internet-explorer-9, settings

[image: I do not want this to appear each time]

I have already enabled scripts from Tools->Security->Custom...

...Please help migrate to proper forum/sub-site if not relevant here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the security alert of the security zone that the web site belong to.

It will be done under InternetOptions-> Security Tab, there select the zone that you want to change and press **"Custom level..."** button.

here on **"ActiveX controls and plug-ins"** section enable/disable/prompt what you want.

Comment: this is not working for saved pages on desktop...!